# where to position the preposition in the phrase:  "not only... but also"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I have the following sentences, of which I don't know whether the prepositions are correctly positioned:

> The solution depends *not only on* Condition A, *but also on* Condition B. But when C happens, it depends *only on* Condition A.

Another possible way is:

> The solution depends *on not only* Condition A, *but also* Condition B. But when C happens, it depends *on only* Condition A.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This isn't really a question about "not only... but also" as much as it is about where to place the preposition within or around that construct.

Comment: Dear J.R. Thanks for your comment. I have updated my title accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the right one, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Olga S. Do you think the second one is wrong?

Comment: As for the first one, the second part can be also wrote as "But when C happens, it depends only on Condition A". Do you think this is better?

Comment: The position of "only" in the second part depends on the emphasis. You should decide what word you want to emphasize.

Comment: As for the second option in your question, it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Add an "on" after the "also" in the second option, and it would seem just fine.

Answer (score 1):

- When C happens, the solution only depends on Condition A.

Here the *only* emphasises *the solution* and **not** *Condition A*.

- When C happens, the solution depends only on Condition A.
- When C happens, the solution depends on Condition A only.
- When C happens, the solution depends on Condition A alone.
- When C happens, the solution depends solely on Condition A.

These different formulations convey whatever you had intended.

Comment: Dear Shyam, thanks a lot for all these alternatives. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first of your two examples is less clumsy than the second, but both are ambiguous or unclear.  The examples in Shyam's answer remove the ambiguity by replacing *it* with *the solution*:

> But when C happens, it depends only on Condition A.
>   → But when C happens, the solution depends only on Condition A.

However, there is a problem with the first sentence when combined with the second, as the two contradict each other.  The first sentence says the solution depends on Condition B and the second sentence says the solution does not depend on Condition B.  Some possible re-wordings (sadly, convoluted or prolix) are shown below.  It seems that while the dependencies among Conditions A, B, C are not particularly complex, they are difficult to state briefly, correctly, elegantly.

> The solution depends on Conditions A and B, except only on A when C happens.
>   The solution depends on Condition A; solely on A when Condition C occurs, else on B as well.
>   If Condition C occurs, the solution depends only on Condition A; otherwise, it depends not only on A, but also on B.